# What WLAN drivers should I install for Lenovo B5070

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, lenovo-laptop

I have bought a new Lenovo B5070 59-430824 i5-4210U. It came with DOS installed. I installed Win7 however it doesn't have the WLAN drivers installed and therefore its WiFi doesn't work. I'm trying to download WLAN drivers for it on my cellphone but there seems to be two different drivers.

1. [Intel WLAN driver](http://support.lenovo.com/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-b-series-laptops/lenovo-b50-70-notebook/20384/downloads/ds100126)
2. [WLAN Driver (Realtek, Atheros, Broadcom)](http://support.lenovo.com/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-b-series-laptops/lenovo-b50-70-notebook/20384/downloads/DS100127)

I can try both of them but I have limited internet on my packet. They both are for the same model and Win7 x64. How should I decide?

Comment: What's the exact MTM (Machine Type Model) of your laptop?

Comment: A)i've had a laptop where tere was a question mark re that.. and was advised by the manufacturer to try both  B)software audit like belarc would might tell you C)a sticker on the laptop might tell you.  D)Call Lenovo and ask them which it has, they may know details based on the label on the laptop that says more.   But anyhow.. doesn't your cellphone have WiFi? Download it via WiFi

Comment: @MichaelFrank Lenovo B5070 59-430824 i5-4210U

Comment: You could check the Hardware ID in Device Manager. `Right Click -> Properties -> Details Tab -> Property Dropdown -> Hardware Ids`. Should say something like `PCI\VEN_XXXX`. Those `X's` will be numbers and will correspond to the hardware manufacturer. Cross reference with this site [here](http://pcidatabase.com/vendors.php?sort=id).

Answer (score 0):

Alright I decided to try both and started with the latter since it is smaller in size and turned out that does it.

Can't tell if the former would also work since I didn't try that one.